# How to delete a word in iTerm in mac os

Tags: macos, shell, iterm

I am using iTerm as a terminal in my mac. I am not able to delete a word in command line for ex in command `cd /path/to/dir`, i want to delete just `path` word , then how can i do that in iTerm.

basically what is the shortcut to delete a word in iTerm.

I looked at https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/154292/iterm-going-one-word-backwards-and-forwards and `fn+option+delete` is just deleting a single character, not the whole word.

Comment: Me not using `iTerm` but `CTRL-W` doesn't works?

Comment: @jm666 it is deleting the previous word, i want to delete the word, where my cursor is present. btw this is also useful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<kbd>esc</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> should work as a default.

Or you can add a `Send Escape Sequence` based keyboard mapping for `esc-d`:

[image]

Comment: This solution didn't work on my end, `ctrl + w` is the keyboard maaping in iTerm, but i cound't find its `send escape sequence`

Answer (score 179):

Go to your iTerm preferences select "Profiles" then "Key" and change your presets in "Natural Text Editing"

[image: iTerm Preferences]

It should work immediately after.

It works with iTerm version 3.3.12

**Edit:**

In version 3.4, there's a slight UI change.
So you need to go specifically to your iTerm preferences select `Profiles` > `Keys` > `Key Mappings` > `Presets` > `Natural Text Editing`

[image]

Comment: Yes this answer worked for me as well as a normal user of mac the presets for natural text editing are the most natural !

Comment: This should be the correct answer

Comment: This answer works on iTerm 2 build  3.4.13 and macOS 12.0.1 Monterey. It requires no fiddling with escape codes which was a big PITA in the past for me. But I don't know what key mappings it removes.

Comment: You just made my day :)

Comment: Just applying this in 2024 and it works perfectly.
MacOS Ventura 13.5
iTerm Build 3.4.23
Thanks.

Answer (score 59):

This helped me.

Delete a word - Send Hex Codes - `0x1b 0x08` or `0x17`

Delete a line - Send Hex Codes - `0x15`

[image: iTerm2 delete a word shortcut]

Comment: I have the same keybinding for `emacs` as well but when I set on `iTerm` it is not detected from `emacs`. Is it possible to use it only on terminal/bash usage and disable if `emacs` is on?

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.

Comment: In Monterey I had some trouble due to some common options not showing. This was what worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 31):

`ctrl + w` in iTerm,

BTW, in text editors
`alt + delete` to delete whole previous word
`fn + delete` to delete next word